# vb6 project saying crviewer9.dll is missing

Tags: dll, vb6, crystal-reports

I have a fairly old project in vb6. And when I am trying to open this project it says:

> crviewer9.dll could not be loaded

so I presume I need crystal report 9 runtime, but I could not find any source to download this.

I checked Business Object site and downloaded the run time zip files but they do not have dll files.

I did find some links which 'claim' that they have crviewer9.dll files but I am not sure whether I can just download from those sites and nothing bad is going to happen.

I have installed visual studio 6, which contains vb6. 
If there is anyone who has any idea how to rectify this or know where I can get this dll from please let us know.

And,

Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this will help or not, but I have an older VB6 project that I inherited. It requires me to load "CRRedist2005_x86.msi" on the machine that will produce the reports. Perhaps you can find something similar to that on your machine. (It might just register the needed DLL). Did you happen to try registering the DLL via regsvr32.dll to see if that works?

Comment: btw I don't have the dll file... so I was searching for some kind of installer.

Comment: It was for a VB 6.0 project, although the Crystal Reports part may have required the dot net framework. My project references a dll called craxddrt.dll (a CR runtime library). Not sure where to go for that viewer dll - as for downloading them from a website- you're right to be careful, but if you do a virus scan on them first you might be OK. I have taken DLLs from other machines and registered them before, but it's always been from a machine I trust.

Comment: I find this answer misleading - CRREdist2005_x86.msi will not install the necessary components for a VB6 Crystal Reports 9 project.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports 9 is no longer available. However, the last version of Crystal that did have support for VB Active X controls, Crystal Reports 11, is still available from Business Objects. As of this writing (November 2012) it is still possible to get a copy of Crystal 11 by special request. You should be able to convert your CR9 VB project to a CR11 project fairly easily.

The Visual Studio redistributable files mentioned in the other answer to this question won't help you if your getting the error in the headline of this question.

Answer (score -1):

Finally found it myself . In the path C:\Program Files\Common Files\Crystal Decisions\2.0\crystalreportviewers\ActiveXViewer I extracted avtiveXviewer.cab and replace it with my existing files in the same folder . Then I registered crviewer9.dll in cmd going to the same path usind cd and then using regsvr32 crviewer9.dll .Finally it is done .